# Weighted chi square and t-test

Tags: r, database, dataframe, chi-squared, weighted

I want to perform chi square test and t-test between variables of my weighted population. How can I perform these tests using the weights I have calculated?

For example:

```
library(cobalt)
library(WeightIt)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")
```

I want to perform weighted chi-square between `race` and `nodegree`; and t-test of `age` and `race`. How can I do these tests using weights?